# Effect of monotone decreasing function on a CDF (cumulative distribution function)

Tags: functions, transformation, monotone-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

(Expanding the previous post to include another question): I've spent quite some time but couldn't understand the following 3 highlighted expressions (as per screenshot). @Azif00 kindly explained to me the first two (inequalities). Could someone please help with the third one (equality)? Thanks

[image: u]

Comment: If $g$ is an increasing [decreasing] function, then $g^{-1}$ is also increasing [decreasing].

Comment: Thanks, @Azif00. But why is the inequality reversed if $g$ is decreasing? And what graph did the text refer to?

Comment: Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers such that $a\leq b$. Then, a real-valued function $f$ is called decreasing if $f(a) \geq f(b)$. Now, take $a = g(x)$, $b = y$ and $f = g^{-1}$.

Comment: Great. That's a very neat explanation. So I can use that logic to draw a graph of $g^-1$ with two points $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is a bit difficult for me to imagine what the graph of the inverse function would be like using so little information. You can also help with the images on [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-increasing.html) page so you can see geometrically why the order of the inequalities.

Answer (score -1):

$g$ will decrease as $x$ increases in value. Therefore, as $g(x)$ is a decreasing function, then $g^{-1}(g(x)) = x$ is increasing.

So if set for probability changes from $g(x) \leqslant y$ then $x \geqslant y$. So the new limits for integral change from "infinity to $x$" to "$x$ to infinity".

C.D.F. of $y$

= C.D.F. of $x$ at infinity  -  C.D.F. of $x$ at $x$

$= 1 -Fx(X = x).$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).